# Trouble connecting AlloyDB using GO lang application deployed to Cloud Run. Error "IAM check failed, caller does not have required permissions"

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-alloydb

My client's controlled environment may be something missing?
Application details - GO Lang, Deployed to Cloud Run trying to connect to AlloyDB.
**Cloud Run configuration**

- NETWORKING
  "Send traffic directly to VPC" with network and subnet specified.
  Traffic routing - "Route only requests to private IPs to the VPC"
- SECURITY
  Service Account has the following permissions specified - Cloud AlloyDB Client, Cloud AlloyDB Database User, Service Account User, Service Usage Consumer

When the GO lang application is being deployed it tries to initiate the connection to AlloyDB and gets the following error message "failed to set up database connection: failed to connect to `host=/tmp user=cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam database=postgres`: dial error (IAM check failed, caller does not have required permissions)"

Trying to connect the AlloyDB using psql client -

`user@gce-instance:~$ PGPASSWORD=$(gcloud auth print-access-token) psql -h *.*.*.*  -U cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam -d postgres psql: error: FATAL:  AlloyDB IAM user authentication failed for user "cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam" FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "*.*.*.*", user "cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam", database "cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam", no encryption`

I was able to connect AlloyDB in my personal account GCP following the following guides -
https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/manage-iam-authn
https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/connect-iam

Comment: I'd recommend you follow the steps from the [AlloyDB Connect from Cloud Run Quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/quickstart/integrate-cloud-run) in order to set your app to run on Cloud Run successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.

The resolution for this was a change to the GO application code by changing the Dialer as suggested here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-go-connector?tab=readme-ov-file#automatic-iam-database-authentication

Answer (score 0):

The first error means the IAM principal doesn't have the necessary IAM permissions to connect.

You'll need to add the necessary IAM permissions to your service account that your Cloud Run service uses. You'll need to [grant that user or service account the alloydb.databaseUser and serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer roles.](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/manage-iam-authn)

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, bullet item 2, these permissions are already assigned to the user.

Comment: Does your Cloud Run service run with the service account `cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam`?

Comment: Yes it does. It defaults to 'cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam.gserviceaccount.com' via GCP Console. YAML Spec -
    spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      timeoutSeconds: 300
      serviceAccountName: cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam.gserviceaccount.com

I changed the configuration to VPC Serverless connector and got this error - failed to set up database connection: failed to connect to `host=/tmp user=cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam database=postgres`: server error (FATAL: AlloyDB IAM user authentication failed for user "cicd-***@labs-****-****-****.iam" (SQLSTATE 28000))

Comment: Other than checking that your username is correct in your app and database (without the gserviceaccount.com) and that you've enabled IAM authentication in your instance, it would help to see the code you're using.